# How can I return the second column/property of an object in PowerShell?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, dbatools

I want to query SQL Server in PowerShell using Invoke-DbaSqlCmd.

```
Invoke-DbaSqlCmd -SqlInstance DBA -Query 'exec xp_fixeddrives'
```

This will return a System.Data.DataRow object. The object type is not really important. The important thing to know is the result will be different depending on SQL Server language. In French it will be 'Mo disponible' and English will be 'MB Free'. I want my code to work in any SQL Server language available.

[image]

I want to select the second column without using Get-Member. Like the solution here:

```
$RST = Invoke-DbaSqlCmd -SqlInstance DBA -Query 'exec xp_fixeddrives'
$SecondCol = ($RST | Get-Member -MemberType Properties)[1].Name
$RST.$SecondCol
```

Is there an elegant way of returning the second column without using it's name?

Comment: Can someone unmark this question as duplicate? The associated question can't be a duplicate because it refrers to lines. I'm refering to columns. A collection will have multiple objects and these objects have properties. Object would be Line and Propertie would be Column.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is the "elegant" way to do it.

For performance reasons, you may want to inspect only the first object returned to `$RST` rather than piping every single row to `Get-Member`:

```
$RST = Invoke-DbaSqlCmd -SqlInstance DBA -Query 'exec xp_fixeddrives'
$SecondCol = ($RST[0].psobject.Properties |Select -Index 1).Name
$RST.$SecondCol
```

Comment: I like your idea of using the first "line" and not use the piping !

Comment: It's working with $RST[0].psobject.Properties.Name[1], but not $RST[0].psobject.Properties[1].Name

Comment: `($RST[0].psobject.Properties |Select -Index 1).Name` should do it as well